# Combining continuous outcomes in a meta-analysis using same individuals (doses, time periods/repeated measures, and behaviors)

Tags: repeated-measures, meta-analysis, dose-response

In case anyone sees this in the future, this is what I did.

For different concentrations, I did combine them. Specifically, what you do is combine the treatment groups and compare to the single control. There's multiple ways to do this, and in my case I used a tool in the software.

For time periods, I only used the first. A loss of data, but this is what I choose. Another recommendation is to choose the most representative time period depending on your study, whatever that means. If you got the raw data, you could do averages.

For behaviors, I split them up and conducted multiple analyses. I cannot speak for how statistically sound that is, but it appears to be a general recommendation unless you were to conduct a network analysis (which is a monster of its own).

OG post:

I’d like to get some advice regarding a meta-analysis study, and including multiple groups from one study. I’ll preface this by stating I’m very new to meta-analyses and that this is a solo undergraduate project (i.e. it’s a slightly informal meta-analysis), and that I’ve read the Cochrane Handbook and tried finding suitable information.

**Background:** this meta-analysis will compare behavior in an organism exposed to a substance at different concentrations. Different behaviors (e.g. active duration time or distance moved) are treated the same within a single group representing an overarching behavior, as is standard. Likewise, outcomes from different studies are combined into a set of dose groups (Low, Medium, High) that will be compared for said overarching behavior. It’ll be Control vs Low, Control vs Medium, Control vs High. The goal is to know if said substance increases or decreases said behavior, and if so, at which concentration group(s).

All data is continuous, and is analyzed using random effects and standardized mean difference. Intervention study. Means and SDs are used. The articles all fulfill the criteria to be combined. The software is Review Manager 5 (RevMan 5).

In meta-analyses, it’s important not to double-count participants to avoid unit-of-analysis errors. This is the issue. Some articles I’ve extracted data from have compared one control group to multiple concentrations. To avoid double-counting control, it is suggested to combine the arms/intervention groups by calculating pooled mean and SD. This is straightforward, and can be done in RevMan 5. I will conduct separate analyses for the dose groups, and then combine the interventions from the same study within said group. But!

**1)** When I combine different concentrations from one study, what does the final result represent? Say I combine data representing concentrations “1 mg”, “3 mg”, and “10 mg”. Does the result then represent “1 to 10 mg”?

**2)** Some articles include data taken at different periods of time (e.g. the first 10 minutes, the second 10 minutes, and so on). This means I have unique control and concentration mean+sd values for period 1, 2, etc. Ideally, I would like to include these as well, but given the time periods use the same individuals they’d be double-counted if included separately. Can these be combined in similar fashion? For one article, this would mean combing e.g. “1 mg” and “3 mg” first within period 1 (to represent Low as in question 1), then also combine these with the same from period 2. Time is not a matter in my analysis.

However, does this not artifically inflate my individuals when I combine period 1 and period 2? Ideally I'd pool my means and SDs, but given those are calculated based on sample size it cannot be done. Is simply averaging the mean and and SDs for all periods statistically sound?

**3)** One article has looked at multiple behaviors (e.g. active duration time and distance moved) at different concentrations using the same individuals. This means all behaviors cannot be included in a single analysis due to double-counting. I cannot find any information whether these behaviors can be combined (the individual behaviors do not matter in my analysis, only the overarching behavior), but part of me feels it might be weird to do so given the raw data uses different units? If they cannot be combined, I would either have to only choose one behavior or conduct multiple analyses to cover each behavior (e.g. one analysis using all the other data, then just duration from that study; then another analysis using distance instead). But to my untrained ears that sounds statistically unwise. Does anyone have any clue? Can they actually be combined, given in my case I don’t care about the individual behaviors, but rather the overarching one?

*Note: I’ve heard that there are network meta-analyses and similar, but that is unfortunately beyond my scope and probably not relevant. Hence, I’ll follow the Cochrane recommendation and combine groups to create a single pair-wise comparison.*

Let me know if I need to clear something up! Many thanks in advance. If you know the answer, or can point me in the right direction, it’d be much appreciated.